# What is it I don't understand about this Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Visual Studio.
I have two Python code files, one is a module that I have imported and one is my main class.
I am learning Python and there is something I am just not quite getting here.

Could someone please explain to me what it is that I am not understanding in as much detail as possible?

I am getting the error:
"TypeError: must be str, not Lecturer"

I thought that the Lecturer class extending from Employee would inherit the get_name method?
I am using the super() function to pass the object to the constructor.

```
from examplepackage.employee_lecturer import Employee
from examplepackage.employee_lecturer import Lecturer

employee_one = Employee("John")   
print(employee_one.get_name()) 

lecturer_one = Lecturer("Emily", "Information Technology")
lecturer_one.print_information()




   class Employee: 

    def __init__(self, n): 
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self): 
        return self.name

    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n



class Lecturer(Employee):

    def __init__(self, n, d):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.division = d

    def set_division(self, div): 
        self.division = div

    def get_division(self):
        return self.division

    def print_information(self):
        print("Name:"+self.get_name())
```

Comment: It looks like you accidentally passed `self` instead of `n` to `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `super` in `init` of `Lecturer` to something like this,

```
super().__init__(n)
```

You're passing `self` instead of the param `n`, that is why the error says `TypeError: must be str, not Lecturer`. Must be str which is `n` not `Lecturer` which is `self`